# .htaccess help to a beginner

Tags: page-template, htaccess

I have made a custom page template and created a new page which is set to use the custom page template.

My URL for the custom page is now:

www.domain.no/property

The website will have 3 different types of property types (offices, shops and apartments) and what I hope to do is that these URL's (which is 3 custom buttons on the startpage) will point to the same custom page:

www.domain.no/property/offices -> www.domain.no/property

www.domain.no/property/shops -> www.domain.no/property

www.domain.no/property/aparments -> www.domain.no/property

I will then from the URL decide what data to show.

Answer (score 0):

For the syntax of the .htaccess URL redirect have a look here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3374696/htaccess-url-redirect

Then add a GET request to the URL based on the originally entered domain, e.g.
www.domain.no/property/shops -> www.domain.no/property?type=shops

Details here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13988815/htaccess-301-redirect-issue-with-url-variables

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I am trying to avoid using GET and have semantic links.